# checking whether all text field in my view is empty or not objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uitextfield

Need an Assistance.My question is, how do i ensure that all textfields in a View are empty or not ..

I know that it can be achieved by a for loop followed by all textfields length are greater than zero.

Is there any method available to check this ??
TY in Advance.

Comment: Your question already has the answer.

Comment: use `hasText` method like `self.yourTextField.hasText` to know whether the textfield is empty or not.

Comment: I didn't know UITextField has that property for iOS10.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all subviews of your view, and pick all of the UITextField instances.

//replace `self.view` to whatever your own view

```
- (void)checkAllTextField {
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
            NSLog(@"This is a UITextField, length: %lu", textField.text.length);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"not a UITextField");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if all of the text fields are direct subviews of `self.view`.

Comment: Thanks. I added a notation there

Answer (score 0):

You can get array of all text fields using recursive function and then check for Blank in textfield.

```
-(NSArray*)findAllTextFieldsInView:(UIView*)view{
    NSMutableArray* textfieldarray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for(UIView x in [view subviews]){
        if([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            [textfieldarray addObject:x];

       else if([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)] && [x subviews].count > 0){
            // if it has subviews, loop through those, too
            [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self findAllTextFieldsInView:x]];
        }
    }
    return textfieldarray;
}
```

Comment: Why is `x` declared as `id` instead of `UIView`? Why check if `x` responds to `subview` when all views respond to that selector? Why bother looking at the subviews of any text fields?